# Missing value error in if statement

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a data.frame like this

```
home <- c("MANU","CHELSEA")
away <- c("SWANSEA", "LIVERPOO")
GH <- c(3,4)
GA <- c(2,1)

df <- data.frame(home, away, GH, GA)
```

I would like add a column in the df which fills a point column based on the result:

```
calc <- function(df) {

 df$POINTS <- 0

 for(i in 1:nrow(df))

  if(df$GA[i] > df$GH[i]) {
    df$POINTS[i] <- 0.11
  }
  else {
    df$POINTS[i] <- 0.22
    print("a")
  }

}
```

This however gives me this

```
 > df
 home     away GH GA POINTS
 1    MANU  SWANSEA  3  2   0.00
 2 CHELSEA LIVERPOO  4  1   0.11
```

Why arent the points of the first records 0.11?

Comment: that's because `length(df)` = 4.Use `nrow` or `dim(df)[1]`. But it might be best to use `ifelse` instead or a for loop + an if else statement

Comment: @etienne, I tried your suggestion but I still dont get the answer I want. Could you take a look at my edited question?

Comment: You forgot a `{` after the `for` : `for(i in 1:nrow(df)){`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly recommend that data.table is used, instead of data.frame. Data table is more readable, has better support for rules-based data manipulation, and is also much quicker should your datasets grow.

Here's how you could solve it:

```
library(data.table)

home <- c("MANU","CHELSEA")
away <- c("SWANSEA", "LIVERPOO")
GH <- c(3,1)
GA <- c(2,3)

dt <- data.table(home, away, GH, GA)
dt[, POINTS:=ifelse(GH>GA, 0.22, 0.11) ]
```

The first line sets up the data table:

```
      home     away GH GA
1:    MANU  SWANSEA  3  2
2: CHELSEA LIVERPOO  1  3
```

And the second adds in your ruleset:

```
> dt
      home     away GH GA POINTS
1:    MANU  SWANSEA  3  2   0.22
2: CHELSEA LIVERPOO  1  3   0.11
```

I also corrected the bug of Chelsea actually winning a soccer game. Seems unlikely these days.

Cheers

**UPDATE after comment**

Aha. It's basically a matter of personal preferences. As long as you can establish a clear ruleset, there are many ways to code it. Some people like compact code, I tend to prefer human readability.

Thus you could do it like this:

```
dt[GH>GA, comment := "home victory"] 
dt[GH<GA, comment := "away victory"] 
dt[GH==GA, comment := "draw"]
```

or like this:

```
dt[, home.points:=ifelse(GH>GA, 3, 0) + ifelse(GH==GA, 1, 0) + ifelse(GH<GA, 0, 0) ]
```

Check out any tutorial for data.table and you'll easily see how flexible it is for cases like this.

Comment: :). I used an IF statement because I want to distinguish more levels than 2 (5 actually). Would you say if else is suited then? Or should I go for someting like switch

Comment: I've updated the original answer to give some code examples that would work. However you end up solving it, try just to keep the code simple to read, and debug. 

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

We don't need a loop for this

```
df$POINTS <- c(0.22, 0.11)[(df$GA>df$GH)+1L]
```

Or we can use `ifelse` as well.

Comment: @etienne Thanks for the comment. You are right.  The order should be different (changed)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a function and a `for` loop you could do this :

```
calc<-function(df){
    for(i in 1:nrow(df)){ # brackets after the for
        if(df$GA[i] > df$GH[i]) { # no need to initialize POINTS
            df$POINTS[i] <- 0.11} else {
                df$POINTS[i] <- 0.22
                print("a")
            }
    }
    return(df) # so that the function "returns" something
}
```

you can then do `df<-calc(df)` and `df` will have the new column with good values.

I would however recommend using `ifelse` : `df$POINTS<-ifelse(df$GA>df$GH,0.11,0.22)`

You can of course combine multiple `ifelse` statements. The first argument is the test, the second the value if the test is TRUE, the last the value if the test is FALSE.

Example of several `ifelse` :

```
ifelse(df$home=='MANU',0.3,ifelse(df$GA>df$GH,0.11,0.22))
# [1] 0.30 0.22 # as expected
```